# text node gets dragged outside the visible space for unknown reason

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am a newbie at iOS app development and I've been constantly having problems trying to make my nodes appear on the scene as I want to. I have this scene where I am trying to display some text in the middle of the screen and towards the top. I'd have shared a screenshot here only if I had 10 reputation :(

But what's happening is the text node I am trying to display gets dragged outside the visible space for some reason. Here is the code -

```
highestScore.fontName = "Helvetica"
    highestScore.color = SKColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    highestScore.fontSize = 60
    highestScore.text = "0"
    highestScore.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.height - 100)
    // scoreLabel.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(highestScore)
```

What's more weird is that the text node appears at a different and perhaps the right position when I move back to this scene from another scene.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct and you don't need to use the `zPosition`.
Your problem is the size of your scene frame. The `GameViewController`-frame, in which your `GameScene` is embedded, isn't the same size as your scene.

To resolve that problem open your `GameViewController.swift` file and add the following line of code in your `viewDidLoad` method after the line `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

That way, both frames are the same size and you can use your code.

Comment: thanks! just curious why would it appear in the right manner when I switch back to this scene from another scene..